# Writing graphs and inverses and points.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus, functions

If the graph of $h(x)=y$ passes through the points (3,2) and (4,5). What points must be on $y=p(x)$ if $p(x)=h(2x)+3$ and $y=q(x)$ if $h(x)=q(2x)+3$.

I don't have clue how to do this. Can someone show me how to do it with all your work and explain each step.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $h(3)=2$ and $h(4)=5$, and that’s **all** that you know about $h$. What values of $p(x)=h(2x)+3$ does that let you compute? You can comput $h(2x)$ if and only if $2x$ is either $3$ or $4$, so $x$ must be half of one of those, either $\frac32$ or $2$. If $x=\frac32$, then $2x=3$, $h(2x)=2$, and $p(x)=h(2x)+3=2+3=5$. What happens if $x=2$?

The other part is a little trickier. If $h(x)=q(2x)+3$, and you know that $h(3)=2$, then you know that $2=h(3)=q(2\cdot3)+3=q(6)+3$. Solve for $q(6)$: $q(6)=2-3=-1$. Thus, the point $(6,-1)$ must be on the curve $y=q(x)$. Can you do the other half now?

Comment: I can do the other half thanks

Comment: @jean: Excellent. You’re welcome!